# Cordova iOS IAP

Tags: cordova, in-app-purchase, ionic-framework

I am currently using [this](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase) plugin to handle IAP's in my Cordova app, but I am running into an issue and I haven't been able to resolve it using any of the suggestions given on the interwebs.

I am able to successfully pull down all of the IAP information from iTunes Connect and display it in my view, but I am getting errors on the

```
storekit.purchase(productId);
```

method.

Here are the logs:

```
2014-12-03 12:50:07.852 GradeBlade[824:4942376] InAppPurchase[objc]: About to do IAP
2014-12-03 12:50:07.854 GradeBlade[824:4942376] InAppPurchase[objc]: Transaction updated:      panda4man.gradeblade.noAds
2014-12-03 12:50:07.854 GradeBlade[824:4942376] InAppPurchase[objc]: Purchasing...
2014-12-03 12:50:07.854 GradeBlade[824:4942376] InAppPurchase[objc]: State: PaymentTransactionStatePurchasing
2014-12-03 12:50:07.865 GradeBlade[824:4942376] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> Cannot finish a purchasing transaction
```

I am testing on an actual device, I created a sandbox test account, and I have logged out of the iTunes store on the device. The IAP is also cleared for sale in iTunes Connect.

Anyone else run into this problem and find a solution?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I'm facing exactly the same..

Comment: @Thomas I ended up giving up on this if I remember correctly... sorry, haha.